# Dynamic value does not show on html input textbox - rerendering necessary?

Tags: lightning, html, parameters, inputtext

I am setting up a lookup component, but when I want to display the selected option in the textbox, the value does not show. However, it is written on the console, so the logic works. Also, when I replace the value with a static content it works. It seems the data needs to be rerendered. I used `$A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();`, but it does not work as I embed the Lightning component in an app. `Location.reload()` again initializes the entire page, and it resets the page to the original state, so that does not work either.

Here is the picture of the empty lookup selection:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<aura:component Controller="LookupComponentController"> 

<aura:attribute name="accounts" type="Account[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="showAccounts" type="Boolean"/>
<aura:attribute name="showSelectedAccount" type="Boolean"/>
<aura:attribute name="selectedAccount" type="Account"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

<!--Base-->
<aura:renderIf isTrue="{!and(!v.showAccounts, !v.showSelectedAccount)}">
    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="combobox-id-1">Relate to</label>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <div class="slds-combobox_container">
                <div class="slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click" aria-expanded="true" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox">
                    <div class="slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right" role="none">
                        <input type="text" class="slds-input slds-combobox__input" id="combobox-id-1" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="listbox-id-1" autoComplete="off" role="textbox" placeholder="Search..." onclick="{!c.showAccounts}"/>
                        <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-search slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right">
                            <lightning:icon iconName="utility:search" class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_x-small slds-icon-text-default" size="x-small" alternativeText="Account"/>
                        </span>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:renderIf>
<!--Focused-->
<aura:renderIf isTrue="{!and(v.showAccounts, !v.showSelectedAccount)}">
    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="combobox-id-2">Relate to</label>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <div class="slds-combobox_container">
                <div class="slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click slds-is-open" aria-expanded="true" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox">
                    <div class="slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right" role="none">
                        <input type="text" class="slds-input slds-combobox__input slds-has-focus" id="combobox-id-2" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="listbox-id-2" autoComplete="off" role="textbox" placeholder="Search..." />
                        <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-search slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right">
                            <lightning:icon iconName="utility:search" class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_x-small slds-icon-text-default" size="x-small" alternativeText="Account"/>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="listbox-id-2" class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_length-with-icon-7 slds-dropdown_fluid" role="listbox">
                        <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="presentation">
                            <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="item">
                                <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                                    <div id="option1" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_entity slds-listbox__option_has-meta" role="option" onclick="{!c.showSelectedAccount}" data-account ="{!item}">
                                        <span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon">
                                            <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-account">
                                                <lightning:icon iconName="standard:account" class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_small slds-icon-text-default" size="small" alternativeText="Account"/>
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                        <span class="slds-media__body">
                                            <span class="slds-listbox__option-text slds-listbox__option-text_entity">{!item.Name}</span>
                                            <span class="slds-listbox__option-meta slds-listbox__option-meta_entity">{!item.Ecom_Customer_ID__pc} • {!item.BillingCity} • {!item.Email__c}</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </aura:iteration>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:renderIf>
<!--Option Selected-->
<aura:renderIf isTrue="{!and(!v.showAccounts, v.showSelectedAccount)}">
    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="combobox-id-5">Relate to</label>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <div class="slds-combobox_container slds-has-selection">
                <div class="slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox">
                    <div class="slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_left-right" role="none">
                        <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-account slds-combobox__input-entity-icon" title="Account">
                            <lightning:icon iconName="standard:account" class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_x-small slds-icon-text-default" size="x-small" alternativeText="Account"/>
                            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Account</span>
                        </span>
                        <input type="text" class="slds-input slds-combobox__input slds-combobox__input-value" id="combobox-id-5" aria-controls="listbox-id-5" autoComplete="off" role="textbox" readonly="" value="{!v.selectedAccount.Name}"/>
                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right" title="Remove selected option" onclick="{!c.clearAccount}">
                            <lightning:icon iconName="utility:close" class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_x-small slds-icon-text-default" size="x-small" alternativeText="Account"/>
                            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Remove selected option</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:renderIf>
```

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

    //component.set("v.showAccounts",false);
    //component.set("v.showSelectedAccount",false);

    var getAccounts = component.get("c.getAccounts");       
    getAccounts.setCallback(this, function(responseAccounts){
        component.set("v.accounts",responseAccounts.getReturnValue());
    });       
    $A.enqueueAction(getAccounts);      
},

showAccounts : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.showAccounts",true);           
}, 

showSelectedAccount : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.showAccounts",false);
    component.set("v.showSelectedAccount",true);
    var account = event.currentTarget.dataset.account;
    component.set("v.selectedAccount",account);
    //$A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
    console.log(account);
},

clearAccount : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.showAccounts",false);
    component.set("v.showSelectedAccount",false);
}
```

})

```
public class LookupComponentController {

@AuraEnabled
public static list <Account> getAccounts(){
    return [SELECT Id, Name, BillingCity, Email__c, Ecom_Customer_ID__pc FROM Account order by Name];
}
```

}

Comment: it could be much simpler to use `lightning:inputField` instead, is there any issue in using this ? [doc reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputField)

Comment: I want the flexibility of html input as I want to implement several more features than exist at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of aura:if I used the aura:id and hide and show for the classes, and that did function

```
       var showAccount = component.find("auraid");
       $A.util.addClass(showAccount, 'slds-show');
       $A.util.removeClass(showAccount, 'slds-hide');
```